# StudentDbContext is null using Asp.net Core Web api

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

am a beginner in ASP.NET Core. I am creating a Web API service. While I am fetching the data from the database, I had a problem. What is the error I got? I have successfully done the database migration part and created the database successfully.
StudentDbContext is null

**StudentController**

```
namespace webb.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class StudentController : ControllerBase
    {
        private StudentDbContext studentDbContext;


        public StudentController(StudentDbContext studentDbContext)
        {
            studentDbContext = studentDbContext;
        }

        // GET: api/<EmployeeController>
        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<Student> Get()
        {
           // var studens = studentDbContext.Student;
            return studentDbContext.Student;
           
        }


    }
}
```

**Model**

```
    public class Student
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string stname { get; set; }

        public string course { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**StudentDbContext**

```
public class StudentDbContext : DbContext
{
    public StudentDbContext(DbContextOptions<StudentDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }
    public DbSet<Student> Student { get; set; }
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=ams;Integrated Security=True; TrustServerCertificate = True");
    }
}
```

**IDataService**

```
  public interface IDataService<T>
    {
        Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetAll();
        Task<T> Get(int id);
        Task<T> Create(T entity);
        Task<bool> Delete(T entity);
        Task<T> Update(T entity);
    }
}
```

Comment: You would like to get all the student list? Or what? In addition, `StudentDbContext is null` means, in your student table you have data but your are not getting it?

Comment: Have you registered dependency for db context like `services.AddDbContext<StudentDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("ConnectionString")));`? Refer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-7.0/whatsnew#usesqlserver-etc-accept-null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have successfully done the database migration part and created the
> database successfully. StudentDbContext is null

Well, two mistake has been done. Your model has no [`primary key`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keys?tabs=data-annotations). So you will always get null data when there is no [primary key set](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keys?tabs=data-annotations) to your table column.
Therefore, your model should be as following:

**Model:**

```
public class Student
    {
        [Key]
        public int id { get; set; }

        public string stname { get; set; }

        public string course { get; set; }
    }
```

**Controller:**

Another misake is here `studentDbContext.Student;` this will not bring anything. You would be liking to fetch student list instead. So you should write `studentDbContext.Student.ToList();`. As following"

```
        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<Student> Get()
        {
            // var studens = studentDbContext.Student;
            return studentDbContext.Student.ToList();

        }
```

**Note:** In addition, your constructor convension is not correct, it can be written as following:

```
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class StudentController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly StudentDbContext _studentDbContext;


        public StudentController(ApplicationDbContext studentDbContext)
        {
            _studentDbContext = studentDbContext;
        }

        // GET: api/<EmployeeController>
        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<Student> Get()
        {
            // var studens = studentDbContext.Student;
            return _studentDbContext.Student.ToList();

        }

    }
```

**Note:** You can check more details on [asp.net core web api official document here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio)

**Output:**

[image]

For further details you can have a look on [official document here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/)

Comment: Welcomeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee